# Best way to push additional UIViewControllers onto a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm working with the Master-Detail project template that comes with Xcode and referenced in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/

**Problem**: I am trying to figure out how to add additional `UIViewController`s to the default `UINavigationController` that this template comes with.

Specifically, I would like to add a `DetailEditViewController` after `DetailViewController`. Here is what I've done to this effect so far:

In `DetailViewController` I added an edit button to the `navigationItem`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];       
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = 
        [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit
                                                      target:self 
                                                      action:@selector(editDetailItem:)];
    [self configureView];
}
```

You can see it specifies a message selector `editDetailItem:`, which I've implemented as:

```
- (void)editDetailItem:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:
        [[DetailEditViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
}
```

I've created a `DetailEditViewController` on the Storyboard, and the code runs without crashing, producing a black, blank window with a navigation item to take me back to detail. From here on I am pretty confused:

- When I drag a new View Controller to the Storyboard, no corresponding code files are created! Am I responsible for making code files for these controllers? I see that Storyboard View Controllers are associated with a Class in the Identity Inspector... but why on earth would it not create templates for a new `UIViewController` when I drag one onto the Storyboard?
- Should I be using a seque instead of `-pushViewController` to get from `DetailViewController` to `DetailEditViewController`? If so, I'm not sure how to add one on the Storyboard, because the `navigationItem`'s `UIBarButtonItem`s are all added in-code. There's nothing to Ctrl-drag from.
- How do I send information from `DetailViewController` to `DetailEditViewController`? When `MasterViewController` segues to `DetailViewController`, it specifies the `sender` via `- prepareForSegue:sender:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, no corresponding files are produced. How is the system supposed to know what class you want? You need to create a UIViewController subclass, and change the class of the controller you drag in, to that class. The easiest way to push the new controller is to use a push segue -- if you don't have a UI element in the storyboard to connect that to, you connect it directly from the controller and give the segue an identifier (which I call "GoToEdit" in my example). In the action method for the edit button, then perform the segue:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GoToEdit" sender:self];
```

If you want to pass information, then you implement prepareForSegue:, something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"GoToEdit"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}
```

It's a good thing to check the segue identifier first. Then you can access your destinationViewController (you might have to cast it to your class, so the compiler will recognize any property of it you're trying to set), and pass what you want to it.

Comment: It's somewhat common to use a modal transition (rather than a navigation "push" transition) when the new view controller you're showing is for an "edit mode". This answer is just as good for that -- just set the segue type in IB to "modal" instead of "push" and the code stays the same.

Comment: Thanks very much rdelmar and rickster. Really appreciate your time reading and responding. rdelmar: A couple follow ups: My ability to drag a seque from the Detail View Controller to the Edit Detail View Controller is spotty for some reason. Yesterday I was able to make a segue, but then I deleted that segue and now I can't Ctrl-drag to make the seque again. Any thoughts why? Also, do you know how I might get the new View Controller to have a Navigation Item bar? I dragged one onto that View controller and it shows up in the hierarchy on the left, but not in the scene.

Comment: Well, I've recreated the seque by just zooming out. For some reason it seems to work better by zooming out. IRC folk suggested, also, that if Ctrl-dragging a seque isn't working, one can Ctrl-click and use the little circles

Comment: Will add a new question here on SO regarding my other question above

Comment: Haha, sorry for the flood here. It appears that when I add the seque, it extends the original relationship from the Navigation Controller all the way through to my new scene! Excellent :D. Thank you :D